# Как разобраться в отрисоке вьюхи в yii

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Не понимаю как отрисовываются вьюху. Есть такой код:

```
// не работает отрисовка страницы апдейта
return $this->render('/components/system/_update', [
   'model' => $model,
]);
....
//Работает отрисовка страницы со списком элементов
$this->render('/components/system/_index', [
  'searchModel' => $searchModel,
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
]);
```

Где эти вьюхи находятся я не понял. Что делать? Единственная мысль, это использовать не эту штуку **/components/system/_update**, а создать свою вьюху

Comment: *"Где эти вьюхи находятся"* --- в папке `views` очевидно, на крайняк в папке `components`

Comment: Я не нашел их, поиск по папкам и файлам делал

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мне кажется, это что то встроенное в yii

Comment: Плохо искал значит..............*"мне кажется"*  ---- да, кажется

Comment: где эти строки написаны? в каком контроллере?

Comment: в `class StaticController extends \app\modules\admin\components\AdminController`

Comment: вот в этом **модуле** и находится папка views с видами для этого самого модуля

Comment: к сожалению там нету

Comment: с апдейтом вообще ничего нету, а с индексом только это, по сути тоже самое `<?php echo $this->render('/components/system/_index', [
    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
]); ?>`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вы правы! нашел их

Answer (score 0):

При развертывании базового приложения на yii2 там внутри уже есть созданы контроллеры с екшенами и вюхи к ним. Судя по вашему пути у вас проблема явно не с базовыми вювами и вам нужно искать папку components в корни проекта.
По поводу поиска то можно сделать глобальный поиск по проекту слудующего куска кода

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
```

или если вы знаете что модель имеет какие то уникальные поля то можно произвести поиск по етим полям.